# Query a rank ordered License number in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
LocationID, License, Rank
```

Each location can have multiple licenses and they're ordered by rank.

My goal is to make a query that lists them like this:

```
LocationID, License1 (Rank 1), License 2 (Rank 2), License 3 (Rank 3)
```

but I am not sure how to query like this.

I have attempted to make like 15 views that store the values by rank however when joining on these views, the execution time rises like crazy.

Any advice would be great!

EDIT:
So I have pivoted based on the comments, and I have a result set that looks like this:

```
Location ID:
1,                 value1, NULL, NULL.
1,                 NULL, value2, NULL,
1,                 NULL, NULL, value3
```

I want to query like this.

```
LocationID, Value1, Value2, Value3.
```

Comment: Instead of joining after you rank, instead [like at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server). [Or here for a more dynamic list of result columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: I have modified my question @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
MAX(value)
,MAX(value2)
,MAX(Value3)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY values
```